# how to to find the interval of convergence of a power series

Tags: real-analysis

What is the interval of convergence of the power series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(x+2)^k}{k(k+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}} $$ ?
Which method can be applied here?

Answer (score 1):

We first find the [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius) $R$ by using the limit
$$R=\lim_{k\to +\infty}(k(k+1)^{1/2})^{1/k}=1.$$
Then the interval of convergence $I$, which is centered at $-2$, is such that
$$(-3,-1)=(-2-R,-2+R)\subseteq I\subseteq [-2-R,-2+R]=[-3,-1].$$
It remains to check the convergence of the series at the endpoints $x=-3$ and $x=-1$:
$$(x=-3)\quad \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k(k+1)^{1/2}}\quad,\quad
(x=-1)\quad \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k(k+1)^{1/2}}.$$
Can you determine $I$ now?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

The interval will be centered on $x+2=0$.

The radius of convergence is $1$, by the ratio test (as for all polynomial factors).

Both endpoints of the interval are included, as the denominator grows faster than $k^1$.